# how to use env variables in nuxt 3 outside of setup scripts

Tags: axios, environment-variables, nuxtjs3

So the problem is that I would like to use Axios instance. Because:

1. new  `useFetch` is only possible to use inside of components aka setup scrips. https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/data-fetching/
2. community axios module is only possible inside of nuxt2 https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/536 and are nor supported in nuxt3
3. I need to make calls in pinia actions(store) to my backend service.

nuxt.config.js

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.API_BASE_URL ?? "http://localhost:8080/api/v1",
    },
  },
  env: {
    apiBase: process.env.API_BASE_URL ?? "http://localhost:8080/api/v1",
  },
  buildModules: ["@pinia/nuxt"],
});
```

and here is instance.js

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
});

instance.interceptors.response.use((response: AxiosResponse) => {
  return response.data;
});

export default instance;
```

So it does see the envs on server-side as I can console log them but on client I do receive can't read of undefined

Answer (score 2):

You can access your env variables using a [composable](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/composables#composables-directory) and the [useRuntimeConfig](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/migration/runtime-config#runtime-config) method.

Something like this for instance:

```
// file composables/use-axios-instance.ts

import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

let instance = null;

export const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const { API_BASE_URL } = useRuntimeConfig();

  if (!instance) {
    instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
    });

    instance.interceptors.response.use((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      return response.data;
    });
  }

  return instance;
};
```

Then you can access to your axios instance using `const axios = useAxiosInstance();`