# How to Use Environment Variables in Axios within Nuxt3 Composables

Tags: axios, environment-variables, nuxt3

I am currently working with Axios in a Nuxt 3 project and I'm facing an issue with using environment variables within an api.js file located under the composables directory.
Here is my project directory structure:

```
├───nuxt.config.ts
├───composables
│   ├───api.js
├───pages
│   ├───signup.vue
├───.env
├───.env.dev
```

Contents of .env:

```
NUXT_BASE_URL = "/"
NUXT_API_BASE = "https://localhost:8000"
```

Contents of .env.dev:

```
NUXT_BASE_URL = "/"
NUXT_API_BASE = "https://localhost:8000"
```

nuxt.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_API_BASE ?? "http://localhost:8000",
    },
  },
  env: {
    apiBase: process.env.NUXT_API_BASE ?? "http://localhost:8000",
  },
})
```

composables/api.js ( which I learn from [how to use env variables in nuxt 3 outside of setup scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715322/how-to-use-env-variables-in-nuxt-3-outside-of-setup-scripts)):

```
import axios from 'axios';

let instance = null;

export const useAxiosInstance = () => {
    const { NUXT_API_BASE } = useRuntimeConfig();
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();

    if (!instance) {
      instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: NUXT_API_BASE,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        timeout: 5000
      });

      instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
        return response.data;
      });
    }

    return instance;
};

const userRequest = useAxiosInstance();

export const apiSignup = data => {
    return userRequest.post('/signup', data)
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(() => {})
};
```

However, when I run npm run dev and check my /pages/signup.vue, I consistently encounter a 500 error message:

```
500
[nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#using-vue-and-nuxt-composables.
at Module.useRuntimeConfig (./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.js:192:27)
at useAxiosInstance (./composables/api.js:22:58)
at ./composables/api.js:40:21
……
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: (update) 
Aside from the suggestion @Kian gave, I resolved this issue by making two other changes:
1. The address in the .env file should use 'http' instead of 'https'.
2. I moved the 'const userRequest = useAxiosInstance()' inside the 'apiSignup' function."

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issues in your code:

1. .env / .env.dev ( remove "" )

```
NUXT_BASE_URL = /
NUXT_API_BASE = https://localhost:8000
```

2. nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_API_BASE
    },
  },
})
```

3.in order to access it

```
// ...

const config = useRuntimeConfig()

// ...

instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: config.public.apiBase, // you can access it like this
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        timeout: 5000
      })
```

Comment: You should add a small note that they should not do this with private keys, only with information that can or should be publicly visible.

Comment: @KianSalout Thanks but still I see error message :
`500 
[nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug.`

Comment: Hi @KianSalout, I don't think removing the double quotes ("") from the address is necessary in .env or .env.dev. With or without the double quotes, both options work.

Finally I resolved this issue by making two other changes:
1. The address in the .env file should use 'http' instead of 'https'.
2. I moved the 'const userRequest = useAxiosInstance()' inside the 'apiSignup' function."